# Ignore database columns when inserting feature

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I have a spatial table in MSSQL which has a "Geog" column that stores WKT and an "area" column that automatically populates based on the "Geog" geometry.
This table is succesfully added in qgis and shows up nicely.

Now when i try to save a new feature into this table, it returns an error saying that the "area" column values can not be edited because it's a calculated field.

```
 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The column "Area" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement
```

Is there a way to ignore certain columns in the SQL that gets send to the database? A null value still gets send, and returns that error.

I know qgis can do the calculated fields thing but our database works with other apps as well, so it needs to have the area field calculated in-server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you editing a view?

Comment: no, just a normal table

Comment: how does the geometry table automatically get populated with the WKT?

Comment: The Geog column get it's values (in WKT) from a javascript webapp or from qgis (which i'm trying to achieve here)

Comment: If you push WKT into a geometry column it will 'automatically' create geometry - I don't know if you need the extra WKT column ... this may be the issue ... QGIS edits MSSQL Spatial data natively, so if you're trying to use QGIS to create the WKT then push it into a geometry column, that might be an extra step...

Comment: Exactly, here i try to push a feature from QGIS into a MSSQL database. I suppose qgis does it own internal thing to create the string-value that needs to be stored in the geometry column. The problem is that when you push a feature into a table, QGIS sends a value for each and every column in that table. I'm trying to tell QGIS that this "area" column can be ignored, so that qgis doesn't send a value for this "area" field (not even a NULL value)

Comment: Sounds like you're writing your own editor - hopefully someone else could lend some advice...

Comment: I fear that writing my own editor will be the way to achieve it, but i was hoping that there was an easier way. Thanks for you help though!

Comment: Do you really need anything more than the QGIS editor will do with MSSQL spatial? Web is another story, but...

Comment: all i need more is the ability to not send a NULL value for a specific column, to really just ignore that column.